# How to check if row is soft-deleted in Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, soft-delete

In Laravel 5.1 is there a nice way to check if an eloquent model object has been soft-deleted? I'm not talking about selecting data but once I have the object e.g. `Thing::withTrashed()->find($id)`

So far the only way I can see is

```
if ($thing->deleted_at !== null) { ... }
```

I do not see any relevant method [in the API](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html) that would allow for example

```
if ($thing->isDeleted()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Just realised I was looking in the wrong API. The Model class doesn't have this, but the [SoftDelete trait](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/SoftDeletes.html) that my models use has a `trashed()` method.

So I can write

```
if ($thing->trashed()) { ... }
```

Comment: Maybe 5.2 is different, but I tried this and it didn't work. Instead when I tried getting $thing where it was soft deleted, Laravel returned back null, so I just checked `if ($thing == null)`

Comment: @ZacharyWeixelbaum Did you use `withTrashed()` to fetch the item, as I mentioned in the question? Otherwise you won't get any deleted records.

Answer (score 8):

In laravel6, you can use followings.

To check the Eloquent Model is using soft delete:

```
if( method_exists($thing, 'trashed') ) {
    // do something
}
```

To check the Eloquent Model is using soft delete in resource (when using resource to response):

```
if( method_exists($this->resource, 'trashed') ) {
    // do something
}
```

And finally to check if the model is trashed:

```
if ($thing->trashed()) {
    // do something
}
```

Hope, this will be helpful!

Answer (score 6):

For those seeking an answer on testing environment, within laravel's test case
you can assert as:

```php
$this->assertSoftDeleted($user);
```

or in case it's just deleted (without soft deleting)

```php
$this->assertDeleted($user);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the best way

```
$model = 'App\\Models\\ModelName';

$uses_soft_delete = in_array('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes', class_uses($model));

if($usesSoftDeletes) {
    // write code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$checkDomain = Domain::where('tenant_id', $subdomain)->withTrashed()->first();
                
 if($checkDomain->trashed()){
       return redirect()->route('domain.not.found');
 }else{
     return view('frontend.' . theme() . '.index');
 }
```