# How check in PHP if entry in db deleted?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I delete post:

```
$this->delete('/api/posts/1');
```

How check if that delete?

```
$this->assertNull(Post::find($post->id));
```

It doesn't work!

Comment: doesnt the delete function return true on success or false on failure. Most database framework support this.

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
$this->notSeeInDatabase('posts', ['id' => $post->id]);
```

description :

```
->notSeeInDatabase($table, array $data)
```

and

```
->missingFromDatabase($table, array $data)
```

One is just an alias for the other.

Answer (score 1):

Most answers are way to complex or use a extra function to call.
The Laraval delete function returns a boolean or a null

```
/**
 * Delete the model from the database.
 *
 * @return bool|null
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function delete()
{
  ....
  ....
}
```

So you can simply can use this code to check a delete.

```
try {
  if ($this->delete('/api/posts/1')) {
  }    
} catch (\Exception $exception) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check it with `Post::findOrFail()`, or you could just check this `if(Post::findById($id) == null)`.

*Edit*: not sure if this still works in Laravel >5.2 but you might be able to fetch the collection `withTrashed()` if you soft-delete the record. Then you could use `if($record->isTrashed()) { ... }`. This functionality isn't default in a Model, but is present in the `SoftDelete` trait.

Found the information for the edit here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003284/how-to-check-if-row-is-soft-deleted-in-eloquent).

Answer (score 0):

YOu should try this:

```
$post = Post::find($post->id); 

if(is_null($post))
```

Hope this work for you !!!